# Local Fonts doesn't show properly after choosing it from JFontChooser

Tags: java, fonts, jtextarea

I am trying to making a notepad like windows `notepad` where user can choose fonts.

But, When I select a font from `JFontCHooser` the `English Fonts` gives me Correct fonts. But, after pressing `f12` from keyboard to change the language breaks the fonts.

And also when I choose a `local font` it breaks and shows me `box` instead of font and here `f12` to switch language doesn't work.

Code for Font:

```
btnFont = new JMenuItem("Font");
    btnFont.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8");
            JFontChooser fc = new JFontChooser();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,fc, "Chooser your font",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            inputArea.setFont(fc.getPreviewFont());
            //inputArea.setText(inputArea.getText().getBytes(), "UTF-8");
        }
    });
```

[image]

Comment: One option would be to test the fonts with a sample of your input to make sure the font can display the text before you provide the user with a list of fonts.  The `Font` method `canDisplayUpTo` performs this test.

Comment: Can you provide an example please? @GilbertLeBlanc

Comment: `inputArea.setFont(fc.getSelectedFont());`

Comment: @DevilsHnd it shows an error. it shows adding a cast.

Comment: Here's one of my projects on Github: [Font Selector](https://github.com/ggleblanc2/font-selector)